# Chat System Using Django and Node Js

Tags: python, node.js, django

I am hoping to make a chat System for a project as an assignment in Node Js and I am a beginner at Node JS ..Can anyone help me where should i start off Node js??? Any good books and tutorials ?? I am using django ..

Answer (score 0):

I guess its better that you start with Django. It is a very good framework. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsorlkAF83s) would help you understand more.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely will need [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). It will help you with making talk node-js with django backend.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) with Node.js to create a chat application. You can find the documentation of socket.io client and server [here](http://socket.io/docs/).

You can integrate with any platform on client side.
Hope this will be helpful for you !!

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](http://Django%20Channels) . It elegantly handles apps that require real-time browser push like chat.